# Why Does the Button Not Size Correctly Until After Adjusting Window Size?

Tags: wxpython

Here's what I have for the GUI:

```
from wx import * # type: ignore

class myFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        
        panel = Panel(self)
        
        GUI_Input = TextCtrl(panel, -1, 'Enter the length and height of the pyramid in format (a, h):')
        GUI_Input.SetInitialSize(GUI_Input.GetSizeFromTextSize(GUI_Input.GetTextExtent('Enter the length and height of the pyramid in format (a, h):')))
        run_formulas = Button(panel, -1, 'Calculate?') 
        boxsize = BoxSizer(orient=VERTICAL)
        boxsize.AddMany(
            [
                (GUI_Input, 0, EXPAND|ALL, 2),
                (run_formulas, 3, EXPAND|ALL, 10)
            ]
        )
        boxsize.SetSizeHints(self)
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(boxsize)
        
app = App()
frame = myFrame(None, title='Compute LSA and V')
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

When I run the program the window open like:

[image]

But it should appear like this (and does so after readjusting the window manually):
[image]

I'm not quite sure why the button is hidden until after manually readjusting, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In addition to confusing me with your lack of references to `wx` as in `Frame` rather than `wx.Frame`, I suspect using `boxsize.SetSizeHints(self)` is probably confusing matters as well.

Your code amended slightly:

```
import wx

class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        GUI_Input = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, 'Enter the length and height of the pyramid in format (a, h):')
        GUI_Input.SetInitialSize(GUI_Input.GetSizeFromTextSize(GUI_Input.GetTextExtent('Enter the length and height of the pyramid in format (a, h):')))
        run_formulas = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'Calculate?')
        boxsize = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.VERTICAL)
        boxsize.AddMany(
            [
                (GUI_Input, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 2),
                (run_formulas, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
            ]
        )
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(boxsize)

app = wx.App()
frame = myFrame(None, title='Compute LSA and V')
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Results, without resizing, in:

[image]

Comment: Added import for you